# Uniform variable does not have the right texture

Tags: opengl

Currently i'm rewriting my rendering to use defered shading in any case, for this i also rewrite the 3D shaders and i'm aiming for Physical based shading.

Now something strange happens, while it worked all the time before and is still working with all other shaders, the uniform variable is not working anymore like expected. If i assign 2 textures two the different texture slots it shows always only one of them.

Basically i'm calling the following to bind my texture:

```
glActiveTexture(slot); // slot is GL_TEXTURE0 = 0x84C0 + _TextureCount
glBindTexture(type, handle);
glUniform1i(uniform.Location, _TextureCount);
// Always passing, so the uniform is assigned to the right shader
Debug.Assert(_TextureCount == glGetUniformiv(_ShaderHandle, uniform.Location));
_TextureCount++;
```

No error is generated by OpenGL and all uniform locations are correct ( Checked each of them! ). If i insert a third texture into the shader the first is still not visible, but the second and the third are. Of course if i use only one texture, the texture is visible. Also it seems like its not the texture itself, all are RGB565 and if i switch the order in which they are loaded always the last one is working.

This looks like a error somehow, but this error is completly new, before switching to MRT the shaders worked.

#### The Shader

```
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUV0;
varying mat3 vTangentToWorld;

uniform float uRoughness;
uniform float uMetallic;
uniform sampler2D uDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D uDiffuse2;
uniform sampler2D uNormals;

  
void PS_SHADER() // PS_SHADER is defined as main
{
    vec4 diffuse =  texture2D(uDiffuse2, vUV0) * uRoughness + (1 - uRoughness) * texture2D(uDiffuse, vUV0);
    vec3 specular = (diffuse.xyz * uMetallic) + (uSpecular * (1 - uMetallic));
    vec3 normalTexture = texture2D(uNormals, vUV0).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec3 normal = normalTexture * vTangentToWorld;

    // Output the data into the deferred pipeline
    // Color component
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4((diffuse * (1 - uMetallic)).xyz, diffuse.a);
    //  Normal and roughness
    gl_FragData[1] = vec4((normalize(normal) + 1) / 2, uRoughness);
    // Specular component
    gl_FragData[2] = vec4(specular, UNUSED);
}
```

#### MRT setup

The MRT is working. I generate a framebuffer and attach 4 textures for rendering to it bound to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2` and of course i have a `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`.

Before rendering i bind the target framebuffer ( `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _FramebufferHandle)` ), and call `glDrawBuffers` with the color attachments only.

Comment: "If i assign 2 textures two the same texture slot it shows always only one of them." What is that supposed to mean? Yoor code implies that you use the term "texture slot" for _texture unit_. And you can of course not bind multiply textures to the same unit that way. OTOH, you could also implies that you increase `_TextureCount`, and indircetly `slot`, for every texture. Not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: @derhass Was just a wording error, meant to different texture slots.

Comment: Is your shader compiling without errors? Is uRoughness between 0 and 1?

Comment: @fintelia Yes, i'm checked both!