# UBO fixed location not working

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

I have a mystery problem with my fragment shader.

If i specify the UBO's location it doesn't display anything. Same shader without `location=0` works fine - in that case it's location is 0, as `glGetUniformBlockIndex(hProgram, "color")` returns. With `location=0` it returns `-1`;

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec2 uv;
layout(location = 4) uniform sampler2D tex;
layout(std140, binding=3, location=0) uniform color{
  vec4 inColor;
};

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main(){
  outColor = inColor * texture2D(tex, uv);
}
```

Comment: I know this kind of bugs, often it seems like a driver bug.Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062177/uniform-variable-does-not-have-the-right-texture Really hard to debug.

Comment: I assume that last tidbit (`layout=0`) is a typo and should read `location=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not valid GLSL. The `location` qualifier cannot be applied to uniform blocks.

The table in section 4.4 "layout qualifiers" of the [GLSL 4.40 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) lists the `location=` qualifier as only valid for indivual variables, but not for blocks or block members in the `uniform` case (it is allowed in `in`/`out` interface blocks, but that is a whole different story).

Actually, it is totally unclear what a `location` for an UBO block is even *supposed* to mean. UBOs do not have locations, nor do the variables inside them. These variables are only adressed by their byte offset inside the buffer, which is defined by the implementation or by the rules of the layout you chose (like `std140`).

See also Issue 1 in the [`GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object` specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt)

> (1) How are offsets to elements in a uniform buffer correlated to 
>       uniform locations?
>
> Resolved: Traditional uniform locations were used in the glUniform
>           API to access the private uniform storage.  This API does not allow
>           the use of `glUniform` to update uniforms stored in uniform blocks.
>           Instead it uses the various means to update buffer objects, and
>           exposes the byte offsets of the uniforms in the buffer object. So,
>           in short, uniform locations and uniform offsets are similar concepts
>           but unrelated.

To conclude: Your shader should just not even compile with that `location` qualifier in there. And it probably doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. With `#version 440` it compiles successful - but Nvidia compiles & executes nearly all :D. With `#version 430` it fails with error "need at least 440 or extension XYZ".